# How to query many to many that might not exist?

Tags: mysql

Say I have these tables and values

```
table actors
id  int  11  primary key auto_increment
name  varchar  30

table movies
id  int  11  primary key auto_increment
name  varchar  30

table actors_movies
actor_id  int  11
movie_id  int  11
```

How would I query the database to get all actors and movies they are in?

For example, something like this:

Select actors.name, movies.name from ......(QUERY)....

And the output would be something like this

```
actors.name movies.name movies.name movies.name
Bob         Movie A     NULL        NULL
Melissa     Movie A     Movie B     NULL
Rick        NULL        NULL        Movie C
```

Comment: I am curious that why can't you just have comma seperated list of movies in the second column.

Comment: @vatsalmevada If that's possible I'd love that too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comma-separated:

```
SELECT actors.name, GROUP_CONCAT(movies.name)
FROM actors_movies
LEFT JOIN actors ON actors.id = actors_movies.actor_id
LEFT JOIN movies ON movies.id = actors_movies.movie_id
GROUP BY actors_movies.actor_id
```

Output will be something like this:

```
+-------------+---------------------------+
| name        | GROUP_CONCAT(movies.name) |
+-------------+---------------------------+
| Bob         | Movie A                   |
| Melissa     | Movie A,Movie B           |
| Rick        | Movie C                   |
+-------------+---------------------------+
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04c0a2/1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need separate columns, here's one option using `conditional aggregation` with a `cross join` and an `outer join`:

```
select a.name, 
       max(case when am.movie_id = 1 then m.name end) movie1,
       max(case when am.movie_id = 2 then m.name end) movie2,
       max(case when am.movie_id = 3 then m.name end) movie3
from actors a cross join movies m 
     left join actors_movies am on a.id = am.actor_id and m.id = am.movie_id
group by a.id, a.name
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83c276/1)